# Tableview cells only displaying correctly on scroll up

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I'm struggling with creating a tableview with custom, subclassed cells created in storyboards.
All the cells work well except the "questionCell". This cell only shows a fragment of its textfield (or sometimes none of it) until I scroll down and then back up again.

The initial appearance: 
[image]

After scrolling down then up again:

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"TextCell";
static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"QuestionCell";
static NSString *CellIdentifier3 = @"ImageCell";

NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
NSInteger row = indexPath.row;

UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

if (section == 0){
    //the intro section
    TextCell *textCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1 forIndexPath:indexPath];
    textCell.labelText.text = _intro;
    cell = textCell;
} else if (section == 4){
    //this is the "the answer is . . ." section
    TextCell *textCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1 forIndexPath:indexPath];
    textCell.labelText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The only EOM to not be eliminated is %@",_theAnswer];
    cell = textCell;
} else {
    if (row == 0) {
        NSString *item = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"question_%li", (long) section];
        NSString *txt = [self valueForKey: item];
        QuestionCell *qCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2 forIndexPath:indexPath];
        qCell.questionText.text = txt;
        cell = qCell;

    } else if (row == 1) {
        NSString *item = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"img_%li", (long)section];
        NSString *img = [self valueForKey: item];
        ImageCell *iCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier3 forIndexPath:indexPath];
        iCell.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed: img];
        cell = iCell;
    } else {
        TextCell *textCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1 forIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSString *item = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"explain_%li", (long)section];
        NSString *txt = [self valueForKey: item];
        textCell.labelText.text = txt;
        cell = textCell;
    }
}
return cell;
}
```

Here's heightForRowAtIndexPath. The results are the same if I just comment this out and set the heights in the prototype cells.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
// Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.

CGFloat hgt = 70;

if (indexPath.section == 0){
    //the intro
    hgt = 150;
} else if (indexPath.section == 4){
    //the "answer is . . ."
    hgt = 100;
} else {
    if (indexPath.row == 1) {
        //the image
        hgt = 225;
    } else if (indexPath.row == 2){
        //the discussion
        hgt = 180;
    }
}

return hgt;

}
```

the questionCell just sets the iboutlet:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface QuestionCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic)  IBOutlet UITextView *questionText;

@end
```

Comment: one thing that could be better is to use switch statements then return the cell on each case.

Comment: Can you post the QuestionCell code and if present, heightForRowAtIndexPath method?